# How does one go from a string to the contents of a variable with the same name?

Tags: expression-manipulation

What command should I use if I want to convert a string to the contents of a variable with the same name as the contents of that string withing a function. ToExpression[] doesn't seem to do it.

```
func[var_String]:=Module[{var1,var2},var1="some words";var2="other words";ToExpression[var]]

func["var1"]
var1
```

I want the outcome in this example to be "some words".

Comment: Your example produces `"a very big deal"` for me (V9.0.1, Mac).

Comment: It's also successful for me (v10.0.0.0, Windows).

Comment: My example was overly simplified. Sorry. Better example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `Block` instead of `Module`.  It changes the extent to which the variables are localized.

```
func[var_String] := Block[{var1, var2},var1="some words";var2="other words";ToExpression[var]];
func["var1"]
(*Out[2]="some words"*)
```

Comment: You can see why `Module` did not work by evaluating this: `Clear[func]; 
func[var_String] := 
 Module[{var1, var2}, Print[{var1, var2}]; 
  ToExpression[var]]; func["var1"]`

Comment: @seismatica, that's a great point, and evaluating the same thing with `Block` instead 'Module' makes it really clear what the difference is between them, more than reading about lexical versus dynamic scoping.

Comment: FYI `Symbol` does the same job as `ToExpression` here.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```
Clear[func]
func[var_String] := Switch[var,
   "var1", "some words",
   "var2", "other words"];
{func["var1"], func["var2"]}
(* {"some words", "other words"} *)
```